# 4 ton air handler with 3.5 ton air conditioner

Tags: hvac

What effect will having a 3.5 ton air conditioner used with a 4 ton air handler have on the energy efficiency of the hvac system?

Right now we seem to be using a lot of energy per month. The question is it coming from the above mis match if it is, to how much magnitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively large evaporator and fan used with a smaller compressor will not remove humidity as well . The evaporator will not be as cold so will not condense out as much water. The newer multi-speed units can be adjusted for this factor and result in different levels of humidity. With lower humidity people are comfortable at a higher temperature so there can be some power savings.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 ton rating is a nominal rating indicating that it is designed to be used on an A/C systems up to 4 tons. It has nothing to do with what you are assuming  is excessive electrical consumption.